# How to set icon to items of listview?

Tags: android

I have a listview with many items and an icon for all.I want to set icon for each item with java code or xml layout

picture:http://axgig.com/images/29987820360372481858.png

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {



    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);

        myArray=new ArrayList<String>();

    final ListView lv =(ListView) findViewById(R.id.li1);

    myArray.add("1" );
    myArray.add("2");
    myArray.add("3");
    myArray.add("4");
    myArray.add("5");

    ad = new ArrayAdapter <String> (this , R.layout.text ,myArray);
    lv.setAdapter(ad);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a `custom Adapter` to push icons into the list view.
follow [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)  tutorial for better understanding